# Is a gridview of black squares going to affect performance more than a gridview of white squares?

Tags: android

If I have a gridview and I set the grid thumbnails backgrounds programmatically to BLACK, would it consume more CPU rather than if they were white?

```
holder.ivImageThumbnail.setImageDrawable(null);
holder.ivImageThumbnail.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: I don't think you'll see any performance change on the CPU. You might see a tiny change in memory usage using white over black because white consists of a larger amount of data than black. If I had to choose I would think not setting any background would be the quickest. Rather worry about optimising your bitmaps than the color of the background that will not be seen.

Comment: so white pixels contain more data than black? what is the reason behind this?

Comment: White has an RGB value of 255, 255, 255 where black is 0, 0, 0, also depends on the amount of bits in your image. If you take a 500x500 white image with JPEG compression and compare it to a black 500x500 image with JPEG compression you will see more than a 20Kib difference. Change that to PNG and the range will differ even more because of the alpha value PNG adds to the compression. See this article for more http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/bitmaps/

Comment: okay but I am not setting a white or black background image, I am setting a background color to the view canvas programmatically. does that make any difference in regards to what you said?

Comment: No it doesn't. The color rendered on the canvas still contains that data. In android you won't notice the background color memory usage, because a gridview recycles there are only n amount of items you can set to the view before it recycles so you shouldn't worry about the color of the background. Rather worry about the optimisation of the images set in the GridView because thats where you can run into memory issues.

Comment: Thank you. So all in all there won't be CPU related issues - it takes the same time to draw black or white pixels, right?

Comment: Yes. The user will never notice the difference between drawing either of those colors.

Comment: This could be added as an answer

Comment: Cool I did that. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll see any performance change on the CPU. In android you won't notice the background color memory usage, because of the `GridView` you're using. A `GridView` recycles its views thus there will only be x amount of items you can set to its child views before it re-uses the older views so you shouldn't worry about the color of the background.

You might see a tiny change in memory usage using white over black because white consists of a larger amount of data than black. White has an RGB value of [255, 255, 255] where black is [0, 0, 0], size also depends on the amount of bits in your image.

If you take a 500x500 white image with JPEG compression and compare it to a black 500x500 image with JPEG compression you will see more than a 20Kib difference. Change that to PNG and the range will differ even more because of the alpha value PNG adds to the compression. This shouldn't be an issue though because you are drawing onto the `View`'s `Canvas`.